# Cannot find the setter for attribute '{attribute}' with parameter type {type} on {View}

Tags: android, android-data-binding

Не первый день имею дело с замечательной библиотекой Android Data Binding, но сейчас не понимаю причину, по которой возникает ошибка. Я сделал BindingAdapter

```
@BindingAdapter(value = {"menu", "menuItemClick"}, requireAll = false)
public static void setMenu(View view, int menu, PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener listener) {
    if (menu == 0 || menu == -1) {
        return;
    }

    view.setOnClickListener(v -> {
        PopupMenu popup = new PopupMenu(v.getContext(), view);
        //Inflating the Popup using xml file
        popup.getMenuInflater().inflate(menu, popup.getMenu());
        popup.setOnMenuItemClickListener(listener);
        popup.show();
    });
}
```

Далее в разметке определил View

```
<FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="@dimen/fields_edit_hint_length"
            android:layout_height="52dp"
            android:layout_gravity="end"
            app:menu="@{item.getTypesMenuRes()}"
            app:menuItemClick="@{item}"
            app:visible="@{item.value.length!= 0 &amp;&amp; !item.isFieldLocked()}"/>
```

Метод getTypesMenuRes возвращает int, как и объявлено

```
 public int getTypesMenuRes() {
    switch (type()) {
        case PhoneNumber:
            return R.menu.edit_fields_phone_types;
        case Email:
            return R.menu.edit_fields_email_types;
        default:
            return -1;
    }
}
```

но при этом я получаю ошибку компиляции:

```
Error:(67, 29) Cannot find the setter for attribute 'app:menu' with parameter type int on android.widget.FrameLayout.
```

Я использую в BindingAdapter View вместо FrameLayout, но это допустимо, т.к. оно выше в иерархии (и я так делал неоднократно), поэтому я совершенно не понимаю в чем может быть дело. Посоветуете что-нибудь?

Answer (score 1):

Разобрался. Я использовал в BindingAdapter  `android.support.v7.widget.PopupMenu;` , а класс `Field` расширил интерфейсом `android.widget.PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener;` в резултате у меня не искался адаптер и не связвался метод с разметкой